# Trying to run a Rinkeby testnet node on windows

Tags: nodes, rinkeby

Im trying to run a light node om windows, it works until here:

```
geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby init rinkeby.json
```

but when I type this:

```
geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --syncmode=light --ethstats='testnode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303
```

the command prompt says : " invalid command: "my" "

Answer (score 1):

have you tried changing the quotes on " ? This is worked fine on windows 10.

```
geth --networkid=4 --datadir=C:/ethereum/.rinkeby --syncmode=light --ethstats="testnode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io" --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303
```